# SQL Server - Collapse repeat values in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a listing of services at different levels of care that I want to collapse removing duplicate services at the same level of care. Here are some source rows:

```
id          num         loc                  svc_date
----------- ----------- -------------------- ----------
1           1           ACT                  2019-07-01
1           2           ACT                  2019-07-01
1           3           CS                   2019-08-10
1           4           OP                   2019-10-01
1           5           OP                   2019-11-01
1           6           OP                   2019-12-01
2           1           OP                   2019-01-03
2           2           CM                   2019-02-07
2           3           UO                   2019-02-20
2           4           CS                   2019-02-21
2           5           CS                   2019-02-22
2           6           OP                   2019-03-11
3           1           CS                   2019-05-06
3           2           JAIL                 2019-05-07
4           1           IP                   2019-04-20
4           2           OP                   2019-04-22
4           3           OP                   2019-05-22
5           1           UO                   2019-06-09
```

Here's what I would like the result to look like:

```
id          newnum         loc
----------- ----------- --------------------
1           1           ACT
1           2           CS
1           3           OP
2           1           OP
2           2           CM
2           3           UO
2           4           CS
2           5           OP
3           1           CS
3           2           JAIL
4           1           IP
4           2           OP
5           1           UO
```

I couldn't figure out a simple set way to do it through set ops and ended up writing this abomination which is still executing hours later. I tested it on a small number of records and it ran fast, but I obviously did something wrong.

```
--collapse locs
declare @id int
declare @num int
declare @newnum int
declare @maxid int
declare @maxnum int
declare @loc varchar(20)

set @id = 1
set @num = 1
set @newnum = 1
set @maxid = (select max(id) from #tmp_svc_list)
set @loc = 'x'

truncate table #tmp_loc
while @id <= @maxid
begin 
    set @maxnum = (select max(num) from #tmp_svc_list where id = @id)
    if @loc <> (select svc_loc from #tmp_svc_list where id = @id and num = @num) and @num <= @maxnum
        begin
            set @loc = (select svc_loc from #tmp_svc_list where id = @id and num = @num)
            insert into #tmp_loc select id, @newnum, svc_loc from #tmp_svc_list where id = @id and num = @num
            set @num = @num + 1
            set @newnum = @newnum + 1
        end
    else if @loc = (select svc_loc from #tmp_svc_list where id = @id and num = @num) and @num <= @maxnum
        begin
            set @num = @num + 1
            if @num > @maxnum
                begin
                    set @id = @id + 1
                    set @num = 1
                    set @newnum = 1
                    set @loc = 'x'
                end
        end 
end
```

Here is a sample services table to play with:

```
create table #svc (
id int,
num int,
loc varchar(20),
svc_date date
)

truncate table #svc
insert into #svc values
(1,1,'ACT', '2019-07-01'),
(1,2,'ACT', '2019-07-01'),
(1,3,'CS', '2019-08-10'),
(1,4,'OP', '2019-10-01'),
(1,5,'OP', '2019-11-01'),
(1,6,'OP', '2019-12-01'),
(2,1,'OP', '2019-01-03'),
(2,2,'CM', '2019-02-07'),
(2,3,'UO', '2019-02-20'),
(2,4,'CS', '2019-02-21'),
(2,5,'CS', '2019-02-22'),
(2,6,'OP', '2019-03-11'),
(3,1,'CS', '2019-05-06'),
(3,2,'JAIL', '2019-05-07'),
(4,1,'IP', '2019-04-20'),
(4,2,'OP', '2019-04-22'),
(4,3,'OP', '2019-05-22'),
(5,1,'UO', '2019-06-09')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want aggregation, and then `row_number()`:

```
select
    id,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by svc_date) newnum,
    loc
from (select id, loc, min(svc_date) svc_date from #svc group by id, loc) t
order by id, newnum
```

SQL Server would also let you mix aggregation and window functions as follows:

```
select 
    id, 
    loc, 
    row_number() over(partition by id order by min(svc_date)) new_num 
from #svc 
group by id, loc
order by id, new_num
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9aba3bf37e43b07825a21d53a5908999)**:

```
id | loc  | new_num
-: | :--- | :------
 1 | ACT  | 1      
 1 | CS   | 2      
 1 | OP   | 3      
 2 | OP   | 1      
 2 | CM   | 2      
 2 | UO   | 3      
 2 | CS   | 4      
 3 | CS   | 1      
 3 | JAIL | 2      
 4 | IP   | 1      
 4 | OP   | 2      
 5 | UO   | 1
```

Comment: Oh crap ... that's what I was missing when I first tried. The min on the svc_date in the rownumber(). Did not know you could do that. Can I use multiple aggregates in the order by clause?

Comment: *Can I use multiple aggregates in the order by clause?* I am unsure what you mean by that. But in general, yes, you can use aggregate functions in the `order by` clause of a query, as long as they are consistent with your `group by` clause.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. I knew I was missing something super simple and the looping stuff was just plain dumb.